Register based VM - byte order - push/load
I need to write a 32-bit simulator for a processor (or a register based VM).
For simplicity reasons, the RAM is a byte array, which I will cast to (int32_t*) (int16_t*) and (int8_t*) when I need to load words, half-wordy or bytes.
(I know that this forces me to align my variables according to their type.)
Now I want to push parameters to the stack when I call a function. And load them within the function when needed.
The source would look something like:
int8_t x = 1;
int8_t y = 2;
foo(x, y);

And the assembler shall look something like:
    PUSH R1
    PUSH R2
    CALL _FUNC_FOO

_FUNC_FOO:
    ; prologoue
    PUSH LR
    PUSH FP
    MOV FP SP

    ; loading parameters
    LOAD_B R1 FP #8
    LOAD_B R2 FP #12

    ; code
    ; ...

    ; epilogue
    MOVE SP FP
    POP FP
    POP LR
    RETURN

My problem is that this code works fine for 32 bit words and even with 16, and 8 bit words on machines with little endian architecture.
The 8/16 bit value will be pushed in RAM like 01-00-00-00 and 02-00-00-00.
The LOAD instruction will load the first byte(s) of this 32 bit word, which happens to contain the correct value.
If I would port the VM to any machine using little endian architecture, the LOAD instruction would load the wrong byte(s).
00-00-00-01
~~~~~

How sould I solve this issue?
I would strongly prefer a solution, which is processor-architectur independent.
Thanks a lot!

You are simulating a processor. There's no reason why that "forces alignment". If your simulated processor supports unaligned access, then that your simulation must support that too.

Thanks, but the alignment issue is independent of the endianness problem.

"this code works fine for 32 bit words on machines with little endian architecture".
I suspect that's more of a case that it works on machines where the native endianness matches the simulated endianness. That's the root of your problem. You're using a native 32 bits load instead of the simulated 32 bits load. That means you're not simulating endianness, nor alignment restrictions.
Note that alignment can go wrong in two ways: either your simulation has stricter alignment (you fail to simulate alignment exceptions) or the native environment has stricter alignment (your simulation breaks on valid load/stores).
The solution is simple: you need to correctly simulate loads and stores. How do do this will depend on your programming language.

Does this mean that my speed-related approach of casting the array to 8-, 16- and 32-bit pointers is irrelevant since I have to read the data byte-by-byte anyway to ensure endianness?

@Traummaennlein Yes, if you want to preserve host-platform independence.

It seems part of your confusion is because you fail to distinguish native and simulated semantics. So, to be clear, you're casting to 32 bits native (hardware) pointers? That's already wrong for alignment reasons anyway. Reading byte by byte fixes the alignment, and then it's trivial to read in the correct (simulated) endianness.

And just to be sure. If I choose little endianness, I can keep parameter addresses (at least, if they fit in one register) all the same (i.e. always the first byte in RAM). Esle (big endian) I would need to calculate addresses according to the size of their datatype?

@Traummaennlein: I don't understand what you mean by "choose endianness". How much of a design choice do you have in the simulation? If you're simulating RISC-V for instance, you don't get to choose. If you make it up entirely yourself, it's up to you including how adddresses work. But "calculate addresses according to the datatype" is always needed since you need to read a byte range, and you need to know the end of the range.

Say, I am allowed to choose endianness. Say I load the register with a 8-bit value and push it to the stack to be a function parameter. The address of this parameter now depends on the choosen endianness. For little endianness, it is the start of the pushed 32 byte word. For big endienness it is the address of the word + 3byte for a 8-bit value.

The task is to show that I can write a compiler. The effective target architecture is irrelevant, as long as I do have a register based VM which can execute the code.

@Traummaennlein:. No. That simply does not make sense. You specify the processor behavior, you specify how its stack works, but specifying it in a way where the push address differs from POP by three is just insane.

OK, I think I do understand the confusion now. My sample code above does not pop the parameter, but loads the value as if it was any other variable. Am I supposed to always pop the parameters? Why?

That's no longer an objective programming question but a subjective design discussion, which is off-topic here. For the given task (in support of an exercise), it can make sense to simply not support bytes at all - make a 32 bits word the basic unit of operation.
